# One tab Sign-In for web password credentials not showing

Tags: google-identity, google-signin

AFAIK One Tap Sign-In is a Smart Lock improvement for seamless sign-in and sign-up flows. It solve 2 key challenges about Developer Complexity and User Complexity

According the docs https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid One tab sign-in support both password credentials and google login (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFGthqwDmc0&feature=emb_logo&t=240)

**Problem** , I'm facing One Tab Sign-In UI dialog show only google account login but I see on chrome://settings/passwords has password in {mydomain}

The password credentials is currently not supported?

[image: One tab sign-in for web password flow not showing]

index.php

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
     data-login_uri="https://{mydomain}/login_endpoint.php"
     data-your_own_param_1_to_login="any_value"
     data-your_own_param_2_to_login="any_value">
</div>
```

login_endpoint.php

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [doc here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/display-browsers-native-credential-manager): To avoid the display of both the One Tap prompt and the native credential manager dialog on the same page, the native dialog is only displayed when the One Tap prompt isn't displayed.

What this means is, the native credential manger UI ([example here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/images/2016/04/credential-management-api/image01.png)) will be displayed only when:

1. There is no active Google session.
2. There is at least one password credential stored for the current origin.

Comment: I mean password credential stored not display like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFGthqwDmc0&feature=emb_logo&t=240

Comment: The UI in the video is for Android native app library. The mobile web version one tap is not allowed to display and return password credentials due to security concerns.